# Fade in list items one at a time in different lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been trying to make some cool set of lists show an item at a time. But if I do that using the next method, it gets all slow and laggy. Is there a way to do that smoothly?

Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/GuiHarrison/pen/obsvk) of the thing and the code below:

#### HTML (emmet)

```
(.outer>(ul#list$>(li.left>h3{title$})+(li.center>p{some text})+(li.right>p{some other text}))*5)+button#show{SHOAW}
```

#### SCSS

```
$height: 50px;

*{box-sizing:border-box}
body{font-family:sans-serif}

.outer{
  width:100%;


  ul{
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:$height;

    li{
      float:left;
      width: (100%/3);
      background-color: whitesmoke;
      height:$height;
      border-left:solid thin #e1e1e1;
      text-align:center;
      &.center, &.right {
        display:none;
      }
      &:first-child{
        border-left:none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show').click(function() {

      $('.center, .right').first().show('fast', function showNext () {
        $('.outer ul *').next('.center, .right').show('fast', showNext);
      });

    });

});
```

Comment: That will sound weird but precise it - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BAkah - it's bugged somewhere - but i don't have time to fix it right now - maybe You will have a better luck! :D 
Consider it as a hint! :)

Comment: Have You tried $($(SELECTOR).nextAll(SELECTOR)[0]) or $(SELECTOR).nextAll().first()

Comment: Thanks, guys! I worked it out with a friend, but I tested your ideas thoroughly. Probably went over my head, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out a solution! Turns out the `.next` method is not appropriate for the whole thing because at the end of the first list, it cannot go for the next. I tried using using `.parent` to move out and come back in inside a `for`, but it opens every item simultaneously. `SetTimeout` also was no dice, since JavaScript doesn't wait for the previous iteration to finish (it would set the time for everything and do everything at once).

So the solution as as follows ([also in CodePen](http://codepen.io/GuiHarrison/pen/zuwnL)):

```
var c=-1; //il counter - c=1, show center; c=-1, show right
var p=1;  //ul counter - c=-1, p++
  $('#show').click( function() {
      $('#list' + p +' li').first().show('fast',   // first of all (list1.ul.center)
          function showNext(){
            c*=-1;        // switch li (right)
            if (c==1) {
              $('#list' + p + ' li').next('ul .center').show('fast', showNext);
            } else {      // c= -1, show .right
              p++;        //next list
              $('#list' + (p-1) + ' li').next('ul .right').show('fast', showNext);
            }
          }
      );
    } 
  );

$('#hide').click( function() {
  $('ul .center, ul .right').hide('fast');
  c=-1; p=1;
});
```

The idea is to use `next` only to move inside the current list. Then, if the next is finished with the current, move to the next using a variable.

A little (waaaay) more complicated then I expected, but it rendered nicely and smoothly.